# The binder in android

Tags: android, android-source, android-binder

1. I obtain the agent interface of service manager by ProcessState and defaultServiceManager in android binder server.

   I also get the agent interface by defaultServiceManager in client.

   I want to know if it create new ProcessState object when it call defaultServiceManager in client. If it create new ProcessState object, is it need to open binder device in client?
2. In binder, Client in order to get the information by notify delivery in server. The client end as Local site and server end as client end.

   There is IPCThreadState poll monitor binder drive in server. How to know server send notify information in client?